# MVC 5 ajax call SessionId lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with VS2013. 
I'm facing a concurrency issue. Two controller methods both called asynchronously from ajax are using a List at the same time. This causes the following error:

> Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the
>   array's lower bounds.

which is a fairly useless error.

The problem is that normally both these ajax calls would be handled one by one by the server. Internally the Session object is being locked for that reason.

When I inspect the Session object for both these controller actions, they have a different SessionId. The cookie (seen in Fiddler) is the same. So with a different SessionId, they must be locked on a different Session thus causing the conflict.

I use the Session throughout the project for storing variables so I do know it can work properly.

A very bad hack does 'fix' this problem (only to prove it is a concurrency issue) is to created a static object in the controller class and locking on that.

Why are the SessionId's not the same for these two ajax calls?

Comment: Asp.net serializes access to session state. I do not know if this helps but you can turn off session state using class or method annotations. See the answer to this question I asked a while back, It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734737/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-async-callback-execution-order

Comment: Thanks but I actually want the requests to be executed one after another. That way there is no chance of concurrent db access.