# Progress indicator for long running tasks in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Preface:** I've gone ahead and used [this as the basis for what I'm doing](http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-01-02/asp_net-mvc_3-async-jquery-progress-indicator-long-running-tasks).

I'm trying to give my user some indication that submitting the form is *actually* doing something.

My idea was something very similar to what YouTube has done... Have a bar across the top of the page expand in width across the page to mirror the completion progress of the task being performed.

Here's the jquery that submits the form:

```
    // Task Progress Indication

    function update(taskId, status) {
        var e = $("#" + taskId);
        if (status != "Completed") {
            // increase the width of the progress indicator
            e.css("width", status);
        }
        else {
            e.hide();
        }
    }

    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        // start indicating progress
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("Home/Start", {}, function (taskId) {

            // periodically update monitor
            var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                $.post("Home/Progress", { id: taskId }, function (progress) {
                    if (progress >= 100) {
                        update(taskId, "Completed");
                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                    }
                    else {
                        update(taskId, progress + "%");
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
        });
        // end indicating progress

        // this is the post of the form to the Controller
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            if (!data.IsOK) { // this is some error handling that I need to fix still
                $("#modalTitle").html(data.Title);
                $("#modalMessage").html(data.Message);
                $("#modalDetail").html(data.Error).hide();
                $("#modalDialog").css("display", "block");
                $("#modalBackground").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            }
            return;
        });

        return false;
    });
```

On my controller I have the following ActionResult which are to handle the updating of the progress indicator.

```
private static IDictionary<Guid, int> tasks = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();

public ActionResult Start()
{
    var taskid = Guid.NewGuid();
    tasks.Add(taskid, 0);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            tasks[taskid] = i; // update task progress
            Thread.Sleep(50); // simulate long running operation
        }
        tasks.Remove(taskid);
    });
    return Json(taskid);
}

public ActionResult Progress(Guid id)
{
    return Json(tasks.Keys.Contains(id) ? tasks[id] : 100);
}
```

I may be dead wrong here but I think the reason I'm seeing nothing on the page is that there's no link here between the progress indication and the form submission.

How do I fix this by linking the form submission to the progress indication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented similar functionality to provide feedback while merging multiple ssrs pdf outputs into one file. I had to provide some feedback to the user during the process. It was a pain but I learned that the way **.NET likes to serialize access to sessions** interferes with the way the callbacks are returned. It is possible that you are running into the same issue.

My soultion to the problem, pointed out by [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734737/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-async-callback-execution-order), was to simply turned off session state for the controller method of the client progress postback.

```
//IMPORTANT - NORMAL PROGRESS STATE SERIALIZES ACCESS TO SESSIONS - All callbacks are returned only after the controller method returns
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class MyProgressCallbackClass
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can't have a SessionState data annotation on a function declaration though. Apparently it's only allowed on a Class declaration... Anyways, this seems to have solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: Doh! It is a class based annotation only.

Comment: Now, how to replicate this on everything (ie. ActionLink clicks as well as form submissions) hmmm...